# Ros1_Bridge: Custom message pairing failed if those messages have non- identical names in ros1 and ros2

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon, ros-bouncy, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am developing simple publisher- subscriber with custom messages.

1. The name of custom message file is 'EgoData.msg' in ROS1  and 'Size.msg' in ROS2 workspace. I have done the mapping in yaml file as follows:

   ```
    ros1_package_name: 'ros1_test'
    ros1_message_name: 'EgoData'
    ros2_package_name: 'bridge_test'
    ros2_message_name: 'Size'

        fields_1_to_2:
         vehicleLength: 'length'
   ```

- I have done all the necessary steps for bridging custom messages. After I run dynamic bridge, publisher and subscriber, I get following error:

  **failed to create 1to2 bridge for topic '/chatter' with ROS 1 type 'ros1_test/EgoData' and ROS 2 type 'bridge_test/Size': No template specialization for the pair**
- For debugging, I also checked  generated/bridge_test_factories.cpp, it does not show any mapping of ros1 to ros 2.

2. Now, if I keep the **name of custom messages at ros1 and ros2 same**, say, I make ROS1 message name as 'Size.msg', and then build-run necessary nodes - publisher, subscriber and bridge; the **pairing gets successful**:

   **created 1to2 bridge for topic '/chatter' with ROS 1 type 'ros1_test/Size' and ROS 2 type 'bridge_test/Size'
   [INFO] [ros1_bridge]: Passing message from ROS 1 ros1_test/Size to ROS 2 bridge_test/Size (showing msg only once per type)**

I have seen example  [mapping_rules.yaml](https://github.com/ros2/example_interfaces/blob/master/mapping_rules.yaml) where, even though service names are different, I can see them paired when I print using "--print-pairs". But in my case it's not working for messages. So is it something like the name of custom messages which we want to bridge must be identical? Or do I need to do any extra steps other than mentioned in documentation for custom messages? Kindly let me know the probable finding.

Looking forward to the answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298876/ros1_bridge:-custom-message-pairing-failed-if-those-messages-have-non--identical-names-in-ros1-and-ros2/) by [Rucha](https://answers.ros.org/users/36655/rucha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-27**:
Please consider sharing all your code to check if there is any difference to what is recommended in the [docs](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/blob/master/doc/index.rst). They are supposed to work as-is.

**Comment by [Rucha](https://answers.ros.org/users/36655/rucha/) on 2018-07-31**:
Hi, sorry for the delayed reply. I have uploaded the code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VCDRdK__ZCYbBa6B3nqbKuqj7ZIWU1lW/view?usp=sharing). I am using ros1 kinetic and ros2 bouncy- colcon build. Please let me know if any other information is needed.

**Comment by [Rucha](https://answers.ros.org/users/36655/rucha/) on 2018-08-06**:
A reminder that I have posted code's link in my previous comment, the issue is still not solved. Please let me know your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks @Rucha for reporting and your patience. This is indeed a bug in the `ros1_bridge`.

There is a PR at https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/pull/135 that should fix it, I used a simplified version of your packages to test it (available at https://github.com/mikaelarguedas/ros1_bridge_bug.git)

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2018-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rucha](https://answers.ros.org/users/36655/rucha/) on 2018-08-14**:
Hello, thank you for the fix. I tested it at my end, it works fine now.